# Shift dimension or rollaxis in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to perform shift dimention(matlab) or rollaxis(numpy) in tensorflow, with the matrix. 
For eg. a matrix with shape (512,7,7) to (7,7,512). Reshape will not work as I will get a garbage data. 
How can I do that in tensorflow?

Comment: tf.transpose(a, [1, 2, 0])

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I will answer my question then.
tf.transpose is the function to use. The perm parameter allow us to set the new dimension. 
In my case, the perm will be (1,2,0) since I am going from [512,7,7] to [7,7,512] preserving the order of the 7s in both cases.

tf.transpose(x, [1,2,0])